# Smartctl output varies; some RAID does not contain attributes

Tags: linux, raid, smartctl

I have run smartctl -a on five different computers (mostly CentOS 7 Linux with smartctl 6.2), and I noticed two styles of smartctl output. Why would it change its output format? One style contains a table of Attributes that are explained nicely on [the smart wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.#ATA_S.M.A.R.T._attributes%20%22the%20SMART%20wikipedia%20page%22.). The other is not so explicit, and I guess I have to simply use the **Total uncorrected errors** column. But I wish I could get something as direct and understandable as the first one.

Machines are as follows; all are CentOS7/smartctl 6.2 except as noted:

1. A desktop machine, no RAID.
2. an HP DL380p G8 server with a P420i RAID card
3. an HP DL180 G9 server with a P840 RAID card
4. an old HP DL360 G5 server with both a P400i and "Compaq Smart Array 642" RAID cards (CentOS 6, smartctl 5.43)
5. a Supermicro SYS-1028UX-CR-LL1 with an LSI MegaRAID 3108 RAID card.

On the first 3 machines, smartctl includes SMART attributes which is very nice; here is typical output:

```
# smartctl -a -d cciss,1 /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

/dev/sda [cciss_disk_01] [SCSI]: Device open changed type from 'sat,auto+cciss' to 'cciss'
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               HP
Product:              EG0300FCSPH
Revision:             HPD0
User Capacity:        300,000,000,000 bytes [300 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Rotation Rate:        10000 rpm
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000039578312bc4
Serial number:        44T0A3NDFTM91418
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS
Local Time is:        Thu Sep 10 18:15:54 2015 UTC
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     22 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        65 C

Manufactured in week 18 of year 2014
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  50000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  32
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  200000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  0
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:          0        1         0         0          0      80988.717           0
write:         0        0         0         0          0      16041.817           0

Non-medium error count:       74

SMART Self-test log
Num  Test              Status                 segment  LifeTime  LBA_first_err [SK ASC ASQ]
     Description                              number   (hours)
# 1  Background short  Completed                   -      22                 - [-   -    -]
# 2  Background short  Completed                   -      17                 - [-   -    -]
# 3  Background short  Completed                   -      14                 - [-   -    -]
Long (extended) Self Test duration: 2782 seconds [46.4 minutes]
```

On the G5 or (worse) the Supermicro, I get the following, and I can find no way to get the SMART Attributes in a similar fashion to the HP machine or desktop machines:

```
# smartctl -a -d megaraid,25 /dev/sda 
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-229.7.2.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Vendor:               SEAGATE
Product:              ST300MM0026
Revision:             0003
User Capacity:        300,000,000,000 bytes [300 GB]
Logical block size:   512 bytes
Logical block provisioning type unreported, LBPME=0, LBPRZ=0
Rotation Rate:        10500 rpm
Form Factor:          2.5 inches
Logical Unit id:      0x5000c50075e3261f
Serial number:        S0K2CJ1D0000C44065GJ
Device type:          disk
Transport protocol:   SAS
Local Time is:        Thu Sep 10 13:44:34 2015 UTC
SMART support is:     Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is:     Enabled
Temperature Warning:  Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Health Status: OK

Current Drive Temperature:     19 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        50 C

Manufactured in week 16 of year 2014
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  10000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  735
Specified load-unload count over device lifetime:  300000
Accumulated load-unload cycles:  991
Elements in grown defect list: 0

Vendor (Seagate) cache information
  Blocks sent to initiator = 2366764968
  Blocks received from initiator = 42603654
  Blocks read from cache and sent to initiator = 2410106
  Number of read and write commands whose size <= segment size = 591527
  Number of read and write commands whose size > segment size = 71

Vendor (Seagate/Hitachi) factory information
  number of hours powered up = 6262.87
  number of minutes until next internal SMART test = 52

Error counter log:
           Errors Corrected by           Total   Correction     Gigabytes    Total
               ECC          rereads/    errors   algorithm      processed    uncorrected
           fast | delayed   rewrites  corrected  invocations   [10^9 bytes]  errors
read:   3614146604        0         0  3614146604          0       1143.056           0
write:         0        0         0         0          0         53.204           0
verify:    29492        0         0     29492          0          0.008           0

Non-medium error count:        0


[GLTSD (Global Logging Target Save Disable) set. Enable Save with '-S on']
No self-tests have been logged
```

Comment: Be aware that '-a' and '-A' are distinct and different options.

Comment: You're so right. I updated the question. Regardless, the -a is the superset of -A and it's the parts shown by -A (the SMART attributes) that are the crux of the question.